# DreamHost error when trying to add a domain: "You can't add that domain: already in our system"

Tags: domains, dns, dreamhost

I have an account on DreamHost with a domain name. I have a different account on DreamHost with hosting.

I'm struggling to find information on how to host the domain on the first account using the second account's hosting package.

When I try this, I'm met with an error: `You can't add that domain: already in our system` because the domain was registered with the same company as the selected hosting.

Comment: This is too broad. Can you tell us what you understand and do not understand so that we can help you without writing a book? ;-) If you are at a total loss, okay, we can understand that too. Cheers!!

Comment: I'm trying to host a domain through dreamhost, however when I try this, I'm met with "You can't add that domain: already in our system" because the domain was registered with the same company as the selected hosting

Comment: Oh... I get it now! I am not familiar with any hosting company these days. Have you asked them??

Comment: Unfortunately It's too early here to get a response apparently. We wanted to go live before 8am

Comment: As it is, this question is really too broad. Based on the comments above, it's probably best if you speak with your hosting provider directly.

Comment: I hope that someone can answer this question for you! Meanwhile, I can at least up-vote it for you. Cheers!!

Comment: @dan It appears that the OP is asking about an error message and how to get around it. Seems kind of specific from that standpoint to me. Is that good enough??

Comment: @closetnoc Seems like an error they'll need help with from the provider, who has 24 hour [support](https://www.dreamhost.com/support/). The OP or anyone else however can edit the question to be more specific and it will be added back to the review queue.

Comment: I'm on live chat with Dreamhost, finally, but it seems they've never came across my issue. I'm not sure if I should laugh, but my deadline is cutting close so any further help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: This really falls under the troubleshooting category, which we don't really do here, but I've clarified the question and reopened it. It's still a bit unclear as to what you mean by `the domain was registered with the same company as the selected hosting`, but it sounds like you'll need to remove the domain from the other hosting packing, and then point the DNS information to the account you're wanting to host the domain under.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to host the domain on a separate account than where the domain is registered.  However if you are getting that specific error the domain is most likely set up to be hosted on another account already.

I would suggest submitting a ticket through your DreamHost panel here: https://panel.dreamhost.com/index.cgi?tree=support.msg&